# How to update Eclipse 3.5.2 to 3.6.2?

Tags: 11.04, java, eclipse, ide

I want to develop swing applications using the visual editor in Eclipse, but it need Eclipse 3.6.
But it is already up-to-date using synaptic package manager. Is there a separate PPA for the version 3.6?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an German [article](http://fernmannblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/21/aktuelles-eclipse-selber-paketieren/) that describes how to package your own Eclipse. I just summarize it.

1. Install build tools:

   sudo apt-get install fakeroot dpkg-dev debhelper unp
2. Prepare directory:

   ```
   mkdir eclipse-platform
   ```
3. Download [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) and unpack it:

   ```
   unp eclipse-platform-3.6.2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz
   mkdir -p eclipse-platform/usr/lib
   mv eclipse eclipse-platform/usr/lib/eclipse
   ```
4. Now some commands for the scripting:

   ```
   mkdir -p eclipse-platform/usr/bin
   nano eclipse-platform/usr/bin/eclipse
   ```
5. Paste this content:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0
   exec /usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse "$@"
   ```
6. Make it executable:

   ```
   chmod +x eclipse-platform/usr/bin/eclipse
   ```
7. Now the Desktop entry:

   ```
   mkdir -p eclipse-platform/usr/share/applications
   nano eclipse-platform/usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
   ```

   with following content

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Encoding=UTF-8
   Type=Application
   Name=Eclipse
   Exec=eclipse
   Terminal=false
   Icon=/usr/lib/eclipse/icon.xpm
   Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
   Categories=Development;IDE;
   ```
8. A control File

   ```
   mkdir eclipse-platform/DEBIAN
   nano eclipse-platform/DEBIAN/control
   ```

   with the content

   ```
   Package: eclipse-platform
   Version: 3.6.2-1
   Architecture: amd64
   Maintainer: YourName
   Depends: openjdk-6-jre | sun-java6-jre
   Section: devel
   Priority: optional
   Description: Eclipse IDE, static-linked, minimal plugins.
   ```
9. Now you can build a package and install it into your system

   ```
    fakeroot dpkg -b eclipse-platform eclipse-platform_3.6.2-1_amd64.deb
    sudo dpkg -i eclipse-platform_3.6.2-1_amd64.deb
   ```
10. Done! With this you can install your own eclipse the debian way.

Answer (score 2):

You need to download Eclipse 3.6 from the [official site](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/), there is no PPA available.