# How can I make Eclipse work (bash permission)?

Tags: 11.04, command-line, eclipse

Well , I've tried to compile and install Eclipse 3.6.2 using the instructions in : 
[How to update Eclipse 3.5.2 to 3.6.2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47864/how-to-update-eclipse-3-5-2-to-3-6-2)  .

But Eclipse doesn't open.

```
user@s-HP-550:~$ eclipse
bash: /usr/bin/eclipse: Permission denied
```

**Edit** :

```
user@s-HP-550:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/eclipse
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 70 2011-06-12 18:15 /usr/bin/eclipse 


user@s-HP-550:~$ file /usr/bin/eclipse
/usr/bin/eclipse: POSIX shell script text executable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a little error in that procedure.

Show the output of

```
ls -l /usr/bin/eclipse
```

if it is not executable, do

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/eclipse
```

Il gives an error of *unquoted string*, edit it

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/eclipse
```

and add a double quote at end of `"$@`, that should read `"$@"`

Comment: @enzotib: post edited

Comment: So `sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/eclipse` and retry to launch it.

Comment: @enzotib another error : `/usr/bin/eclipse: 3: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string`

Comment: @binarylife: see my edit

Comment: Yes ! it works now , so it was a permission error and then a syntax error ?  , Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Edited the original procedure, so that others will avoid the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Locking is not possible in the directory "`/usr/lib/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi`". A common reason is that the file system or Runtime Environment does not support file locking for that location. Please choose a different location, or disable file locking passing "-Dosgi.locking=none" as a VM argument.

```
/usr/lib/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/.manager/.fileTableLock (Permission denied)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you installed Eclipse by unpacking a .tgz distribution obtained from the eclipse.org site. such that

```
/path/to/eclipse
```

represents absolute file path of the installation directory - where

```
/path/to/eclipse could ACTUALLY BE /usr/lib/eclipse - for example.
```

Given this, make sure that the eclipse directory itself and all its contents (sub-directories etc. etc.) are owned by root and belong to the root group - i.e.

```
cd /path/to

chown -R root eclipse
```

Answer (score 0):

*For the initial question "Permission Denied" without the `ls -l` edit...*

Remember to mount the partition eclipse is on with the `exec` option...

Answer (score 0):

1. Just move the `.tar.gz` file to your linux home directory.
2. Then extract the file using `tar -xvzf your_eclipse_file_name.tar.gz`
3. Change directory to ~/eclipse
4. Run the elipse program by typing :- `./eclipse`.

[Source](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/getting-started/set-up-the-atlassian-plugin-sdk-and-build-a-project/set-up-the-eclipse-ide-for-linux)