# How do I automatically install repast on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: eclipse

How can I install [Repast](http://repast.sourceforge.net/) on Ubuntu 12.04? I installed Eclipse from the repos, but I couldn't then install repast. According to the site, repast needs Eclipse Helios Classic, while the repo version of eclipse is Indigo.

What is the easiest way to get repast working? That is, I know I could install things myself from the eclipse website. But I don't want to do that: isn't the point of having a package manager that you shouldn't have to do that sort of thing?

To be clear, I'd like to install as much as possible through the package manager.

Comment: File a bug with Repast asking them to update their plug-in to the current stable Eclipse.  There are lots of issues with Unity integration if you use the portable tarball

Comment: If possible, please consider closing some of your other open questions by [selecting the best answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) (if they have one). Consider which answers have been useful and need an upvote. We need users to maintain their questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading [the FAQ on asking questions](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 1):

You can download any version of Eclipse from eclipse website and install it locally from the tarball. Then you will be able to install any plugin, even the ones which are not available in Ubuntu repositories.

Actually, here's a nice answer detailing [how to build your own .deb from an Eclipse tarball](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47864/how-to-update-eclipse-3-5-2-to-3-6-2) - just follow the instructions and then install the resulting file. However, Eclipse runs just fine when installed from a tarball too. You also can have more then one version of Eclipse installed this way.

Comment: I was kind of hoping the answer wouldn't be "do it all yourself". What's the point of a package manager if you have to install everything yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do that in a two step process:

- First add the greclipse to eclipse's software sources using this link via the "add" button in "Install new software": http://dist.springsource.org/release/GRECLIPSE/e3.7/
- Then add the repast software sources with the official link and you'll be able to install it with minimal concerns.

This happens because repast, apparently, relies on groovy.