# How can I run Repast Simphony 2.0 on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation, java, eclipse, logo

I have tried installing [Repast Simphony 2.0](http://repast.sourceforge.net/) using a downloaded version of Eclipse (as per the [Linux installation instructions](http://repast.sourceforge.net/download.html) - although which is the "Classic Edition"?) and following the same instructions with the version of Eclipse packaged in the 12.04 repos. Neither method has succeeded.

How can I get Repast running?

(I do not need it to install in an [automatic/packaged way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130000/how-do-i-automatically-install-repast-on-ubuntu-12-04). For example, could I use the version of Eclipse created by the Windows installer and replace `eclipse.exe` with the Linux Eclipse jar?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve this by following the excellent instructions posted by Meghan Hutchins and Marta Vallejo, as follows:

- Create folders called `repast-eclipse`, `repast-libraries` and `repast-workspace`. (In the instructions below, download and unzip any libraries into `repast-libraries`.)
- Install Eclipse and essential Repast plugins following [Meghan Hutchins' step-by-step instructions](http://agent-based-modeling.tumblr.com/post/54831669973/set-up-repast-simphony-2-0-on-eclipse):

  - Download [Eclipse Classic 4.2.2 (Juno)](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-422/junosr2) (this very specific version).
  - "Install" it to `repast-eclipse` and run it from there. Set `repast-workspace` to be your workspace.
  - Install the following plugins:

    - XML Editors and Tools (from the Juno archives)
    - Groovy-Eclipse (download [the Juno version](http://dist.springsource.org/release/GRECLIPSE/e4.2/archive-2.7.2.xx-RELEASE-20121219-0800-e42.zip) not the version listed on the Repast website)
    - (restart Eclipse and confirm)
    - Repast Simphony 2.0 (from the http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/repastsimphony repository)
    - (restart Eclipse and confirm)
- Install graphics plugins following [Marta Vallejo's step-by-step instructions](http://martavallejophd.wordpress.com/2013/03/24/installing-repast-simphony-in-linux-step-by-step/) (relevant instructions start at "Apart from all of these plug-ins, we need to install three more components"):

  - [JOGL](http://download.java.net/media/jogl/builds/archive/jsr-231-1.1.1a/)
  - [Java3D](http://java3d.java.net/binary-builds.html)
  - [JAI](http://download.java.net/media/jai/builds/release/1_1_3/)
- If you have created any Repast projects already, refresh them.
- Select *Window* | *Preferences* | *Groovy* | *DSLD* and click "Recompile scripts"

To test everything has been successful, you can import a sample Repast projects from the File menu. They should compile successfully and have visible agents appear when you start the simulation.